# String comparison ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, case, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (head,member, familyName, status, timestamp) 
VALUES ('200519221', '200519239', 'Snowtwo', 'unprocessed', '2020-07-23 18:41:11') 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE familyName = 'Snowtwo', status = 'unprocessed', timestamp = IF(STRCMP('unprocessed', status), timestamp, NOW());
```

I am trying to update the timestamp when it is not matched to unprocessed as status. It is not working.

I have tried the following as well

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (head, member, familyName, status, timestamp) 
VALUES ('200519221', '200519239', 'Snowtwo', 'unprocessed', '2020-07-23 18:41:11') 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE familyName = 'Snowtwo', status = 'unprocessed', timestamp = IF(unprocessed = status, timestamp, NOW());
```

And the following is also not working

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (head, member, familyName, status, timestamp) 
VALUES ('200519221', '200519239', 'Snowtwo', 'unprocessed', '2020-07-23 18:41:11') 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE familyName = 'Snowtwo', status = 'unprocessed', timestamp = IF(unprocessed = VALUES(status), timestamp, NOW());
```

I need to update the timestamp only when the existing status is not 'unprocessed'

```
timestamp = IF(unprocessed = VALUES(status), timestamp, NOW());
```

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: *It is not working* - please explain in more detail - do you **get an error** ? If so - **what is** that error?? Or how else is it "not working" :....

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `on duplicate key` in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to update the timestamp when it is not matched to unprocessed as status.

I think you want:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (head,member, familyName, status, timestamp) 
VALUES ('200519221', '200519239', 'Snowtwo', 'unprocessed', '2020-07-23 18:41:11') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    familyName = VALUES(familyName), 
    status     = VALUES(status), 
    timestamp  = CASE WHEN VALUES(status) = 'unprocessed' 
        THEN timestamp 
        ELSE NOW() 
    END
;
```

If the new `status` is equal to `'unprocessed'`, then the `timestamp` is left as-is, else it is updated to the current datetime.

Comment: This one is not working. Is there any other way to string comp ?

Comment: @ahamednazumudeen: you need to elaborate on what you mean by *not working*. This was commented on your question too.